# Migrate Spring application to Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on project, that uses Spring framework (Spring MVC, JDBC etc.) Project is not so big and uses Jetty servlet container, PostgreSQL database with standard DAO classes(sql requests). I need to make it possible to use Spring Boot and Hibernate/Spring JPA with repositories instead SQL queries. I found a few states describes migration to spring boot: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration https://3ldn.nl/2016/02/16/spring-boot-in-an-existing-application-part-1/ Now I make small example with Hibernate - generate few Entities and make CRUD operations with Hibernate instead sql queries.
But I need to update existing project for using Spring Boot and I need to use Spring JPA Repositories.
I add spring boot dependencies in dependencyManagment section. What steps I need to do`s next?

Comment: I would start with an empty Spring Boot project generated with Intializer https://start.spring.io/ and then copy your code to the new project. That's much easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my task and succesfully migrate project to spring boot with JPA/Hibernate.
Its very simple task! and all what you need to migrate is:
0) solve all dependencies issues and remove all  tags from boot dependencies.
1) [How to use JPA Repositories without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931726/how-to-use-jpa-repositories-without-spring-boot/51934099#51934099)
2) [How to migrate existing Spring project to Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951513/how-to-migrate-existing-spring-project-to-spring-boot/52000040#52000040)

that is all.