# How to use JPA Repositories without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have an existing spring 4 project (mvc, jdbc etc) and I tried to port it to spring boot and I can't. (many dependencies troubles, no one can't explain how I can do that). But now I just want to use Spring Data JPA in existing project.
That is a main pom dependencies:

```
<properties>
        <jetty.version>9.3.5.v20151012</jetty.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <hibernate-version>5.3.3.Final</hibernate-version>
    </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have existing configuration, that I completed with entityManagerFactory Bean (that used in all examples).
DBConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.testproject.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.testproject.*")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${postgresql.address}")
    String address;
    @Value("${postgresql.database}")
    String database;
    @Value("${postgresql.user}")
    String user;
    @Value("${postgresql.password}")
    String password;
    @Value("${db.type}")
    String dbType;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        if (DB_TYPE_POSTGRESQL.equalsIgnoreCase(dbType)) {
            return postresqlDataSource();
        } else {
            return derbyDataSource();
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return dataSourceTransactionManager;
    }

    private HikariDataSource derbyDataSource() {

        try {
            String appHome = System.getProperty(Property.APP_HOME);

            Path path = Paths.get(appHome, DATABASE_NAME);
            String databaseName = path.toString();

            databaseName = StringUtils.replaceChars(databaseName, '\\', '/');

            Class.forName(DB.DB_DRIVER_DERBY).newInstance();

            EmbeddedDataSource embeddedDataSource = new EmbeddedDataSource();
            String dbName = databaseName;

            embeddedDataSource.setDatabaseName(dbName);
            embeddedDataSource.setCreateDatabase("create");

            embeddedDataSource.setUser("application");
            embeddedDataSource.setPassword("");

            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setDataSource(embeddedDataSource);
            config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
            config.setAutoCommit(true);

            HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

            return hikariDataSource;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("error connection Derby");
        }

    }

    private HikariDataSource postresqlDataSource() {

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(address)
                || StringUtils.isBlank(database)
                || StringUtils.isBlank(user)
                || StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("error params Postgresql");
        }

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        String jdbcUrl = MessageFormat.format(POSTGRESQL, address, database);
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(user);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setAutoCommit(false);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ru.testproject.hibernate.*");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("test");
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Derby database used for tests. But main database type is PostgreSQL with HikariCP. I'm already add HQL support in project and it works ok. But when I try to add JAP repositories support, I have many problems. I have entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public", catalog = "test")
public class Users {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 64)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 64)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 128)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Users that = (Users) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(username, that.username) &&
                Objects.equals(password, that.password) &&
                Objects.equals(email, that.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, username, password, email);
    }
}
```

And Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {

    @Query("select b from Users b where b.username = :username")
    Users findByName(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

it's just a test repository extends CrudRepository.
For using that repository I've created service with implementation:

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

    void delete(long id);
    Users getByName(String name);
    Optional<Users> getById(Long id);
    Users editUsers(Users user);
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

//    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
//    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        usersRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Users> getById(Long id) {
        return usersRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Users getByName(String name) {
        return usersRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Users editUsers(Users user) {
        return usersRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And I'm using repository like that:

```
@Autowired
    private UserService service;
...
Users entry = service.getById(1L).get();
```

that is all.
I don't use Spring Boot (as said above) and start as application failed with error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ru.testproject.config.DBConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: parallelCapableClassLoaderAvailable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
```

If I comment @EnableJpaRepositories annotation, I have the following error:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.testproject.db.hibernate.repository.UsersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

In second scenario repository is null, Certainly - JPA repo's disabled.. 
Please, help! What I'm doing wrong and how can I make it works? I can't resolve my problem with google and Internet lessions. Maybe because I don't understand what is the root problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974249/spring-data-jpa-without-spring-boot    In that thread, last comment describes the same issue with EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Read the manual https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/ and have a look at the examples https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa

Comment: I've already check many examples and following manuals describes spring boot configurations. It's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you try with replacing @EnableJpaRepositories("ru.testproject.*") into @EnableJpaRepositories("ru.testproject.db.hibernate.repository")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thx to all for Help!
I've solved my issue with the following changes:
1) First of all - I've update spring-context dependency with newer version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

it solves java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader error. CandidateComponentsIndexLoader appears after spring-context 5.0.0.

2) I've add the

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "ru.testproject.hibernate"
})
@PropertySource("classpath:testproject.properties")
@ComponentScan("ru.testproject.hibernate")
```

annotations. Previous changes didn't affect to any positive changes. With 1) it lead to entityManagerFactory error, that I can solve with:

3) Set up packgeToScan for entityManagerFactory with

```
entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ru.testproject.hibernate.entity");
```

with path for entities (Users in that case).

That is all. Now repositories works perfectly. Thank you all!!!

ps: may be, now I can start with spring boot)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not adding the test package ru.testproject.db.hibernate.repository in component scan.

Comment: @ComponentScan("ok.testproject.hibernate.repository"), but it doesn't work

Comment: but error its showing the "ru.testproject.db.hibernate.repository" package. can you confirm you are using correct package name ?

Comment: Yes, i've just rename the package. But you are right: some troubles was caused with wrong component pathes